Python Multiprocessing program using only 2 of the 20 cores
I am new to multiprocessing, so this might be a stupid question.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (64-bit) with a 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700K processor and 16GB of RAM under Python 3.9.19. When I run the following code, the htop command shows that all 10 cores are being utilized as expected:
import time

def fun(ele):
    ele ** 1000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing

    input_list = [1000] * 10000000
    start_time = time.time()
    
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    result = pool.map(func=fun, iterable=input_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time - start_time)

However, when I import some additional libraries (like PIL, numpy, etc.), it seems that only 2 cores are working, even though 11 processes (1 main process and 10 child processes) are created. Here is the modified code:
import time
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os
import torch

def fun(ele):
    ele ** 1000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing

    input_list = [1000] * 10000000
    start_time = time.time()
    
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    result = pool.map(func=fun, iterable=input_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time - start_time)

Using the command ps aux | grep [p]ython | grep $name_of_program$ | wc -l, I confirm that 11 processes are indeed created (1 main process and 10 child processes). However, it seems that these processes are not being distributed across all CPU cores.
After setting the start method to spawn with multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn'), all the 10 cores work correctly again.
import time 

from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

import time
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

import pickle
import os

import torch

def fun(ele): 
    ele**1000 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing 
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    input_list = [1000]*10000000
    n = 250000 
    start_time = time.time() 
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10) 
    result = pool.map(func=fun, iterable=input_list) 
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    end_time = time.time() 
    print(end_time-start_time)


Why are only 2 cores being utilized in the second case?
Could this issue be related to memory limitations caused by the additional libraries I imported?
What steps can I take to ensure that the processes are evenly distributed across the CPU cores in such cases (with fork method)?


"Could this issue be related to memory limitations caused by the additional libraries I imported?" Such questions can almost always be answered with yes. Some weeks ago, only 2 of my 32 cores were used for the build of my projects. My storage was the bottleneck. Since I've replaced it with a NVMe SSD, all 32 cores are used.

I would blame torch/fork, tho I can't reproduce the issue on my machine (even tho it has less memory and cpu as yours). But torch does need some memory. Not a huge amount of it. 0.2 Gb on my machine. But ×10, that is 2Gb that can make the difference. And with spawn method, since you don't even use torch, those are not copied in the subprocess. While with fork, of course you have 10 copies of whatever memory torch uses.

Also, it is worth noting that your first code reads input_data=[1000]*10000000 while your second reads input_data=[1000]*1000000 (10 millions vs 1 million). It is always better if comparison are made with comparable data...

@chrslg Thanks. The code might have been copied incorrectly. But the results are the same. It’s strange that even though 3 processes are requested with pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3), the monitor still shows that only 2 cores are working.

btw, the memory usage is low during runtime: https://ibb.co/fCBvPmN

In order to test your timings I suggest that you start with some simple code that is likely to utilise multiple CPUs. Something like this:
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def fun(ele: int) -> int:
    return ele * ele

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map_async(fun, range(250_000_000))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"{duration=:.4f}s")

On Apple M2, this runs for ~35s - i.e., enough time to run top to see what's happening.
Then I would add your imports one by one (even though you're not using them) to see which one(s) have the most influence over your observations.
Note: On MacOS, "spawn" is default. Your observations are interesting from the point of view of the start method because fork (the default on Linux) is generally considered to be faster than spawn. So what you're seeing is counter-intuitive (to me).

Thanks! I tested the code following your suggestion. The original code runs in 18 seconds with 3-4 cores working. I also found that importing libraries has a cumulative effect: when the number of imported libraries is large enough (rather than being due to specific libraries), the code runs in about 22 seconds with only 2-3 cores working.
It makes sense that memory is the bottleneck, as suggested by @jabaa, because htop shows memory usage reaching 98% by the end of the program. Additionally, using the spawn start method takes around 25 seconds, which is also understandable.
